# First non-repeating character in a stream of characters InterviewBit

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures, queue

Given a string A denoting a stream of lowercase alphabets. You have to make new string B.

B is formed such that we have to find the first non-repeating character each time a character is inserted to the stream and append it at the end to B. If no non-repeating character is found then append '#' at the end of B.

```
Input 1: A = "abadbc"
Output 1: "aabbdd"

Input 2: A = "abcabc"
Output 2: "aaabc#"
```

This is my attempt but I don't know where the **timeout is occuring**.

```
    public String solve(String A) {
        Queue<Character> queue=new LinkedList<>();
        StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder();
        int[] arr=new int[26];
        Arrays.fill(arr,0);
        for(int i=0;i<A.length();i++){
            char x=A.charAt(i);
            if(queue.size()==0){
                ans.append(x);
                int d=x-'a';
                arr[d]++;
                queue.add(x);
            }
            else{
                int d=x-'a';
                arr[d]++;
                queue.add(x);
                while(queue.size()>0){
                    d=queue.peek()-'a';
                    if(arr[d]>1){
                        queue.poll();
                    }
                    else{
                        ans.append(queue.peek());
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(queue.size()==0){
                    ans.append("#");
                }
            }
        }
        return ans.toString();
    }
}
```

**And this is Editorial Solution**

```
public class Solution {
    public String solve(String A) {
        //to store the characters in the order they come, and allow deletion from front when needed.
        Queue<Character> q = new LinkedList<>();
        //to keep track of characters already there.
        HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        StringBuilder B = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0;i<A.length();++i){
            //if character was already there, we increment its value by 1. ELse we put it with a value of 1.
            if(map.containsKey(A.charAt(i))) map.replace(A.charAt(i), map.get(A.charAt(i))+1);
            else map.put(A.charAt(i),1);
            //adding current character to queue
            q.add(A.charAt(i));
            //map has the count of characters. So we remove the characters from front until we find a character whose count is not >1
            while(!q.isEmpty() && map.get(q.peek())>1){
                q.poll();
            }
            //if queue is empty, means no unrepeated characters presednt. Hence, we add #, else we add the character in front of the queue.
            if(q.isEmpty()) B.append("#");
            else B.append(q.peek());
        }
        //we return the required string.
        return B.toString();
    }
}
```

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: What are the constraints?

Comment: Didn't mention any kind of time limit or input size on the platform.